# ajax call using jsonp, how to improve security from just passing the credentials in the url

Tags: jquery, ajax, security, jsonp

I am using an Ajax call (using Jsonp) in a hybrid web app  to retrieve a file from a different server, which is protected by htaccess authentication. I pass the credentials `john` and `jonhpwd` within the url like this :

```
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: encode_utf8("http://john:jonhpwd@mysite.fr/webapp/DB.jsonp"),
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: successCallback,
    });
```

Is there a way to hide the credentials in the url to provide more security to the file ?

Thanks

Comment: can anyone answer this ?

Comment: Hello, can someone answer this please, I need to hide the login/password in this code...

Answer (score 0):

No, everything you do client-side is completely visible to the client. There is no way to hide said credentials other than **not** using this code in a web browser.

You can however send the request to some server-side script that doesn't require credentials and make the request to the other server with authentication with said server-side script. This of course undermines the authentication of the server.